# Memory leak when rendering a product

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have some code to render let's say get top 1 of the best price product. I call the code every second and I see the memory always grow up he never goes down and couple of times I got an error a stack over there. Does everyone know how to solved this big Problem?
Here is snippet code:

```
componentWillMount(){   
            this.interval = setInterval(() => this.tick(), 5000);}
tick () {
         this.gettopthree()
    }
```

Comment: Can you post a snippet so we can see how you're calling it?

Comment: i have change the question